# How to restrict users or applications from using hugepage support?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, huge-pages

We deploy and use (home grown applications internally) all of which actually use hugepages and the `mmap()` syscall. But I would prefer to restrict some of the applications from actually using huge page support. Can this be achieved by any changes in the code or any system wide config options which could be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend setting and using the kernel tunable option `vm.hugetlb_shm_group=<GID>` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or manually through [`hugeadm` command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hugeadm). The example below means only members of group mygroup(2341) can allocate "huge" Shared memory segment

```
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 2341
```

Note: Only (the users part of) the group listed in `vm.hugetlb_shm_group` kernel tunable, sysctl will be able to use `shmget()` and `shmat()` calls to access the HugePages. However any user calling mmap() can access HugePages. Your code may require some some changes accordingly, if only using `mmap()`.

Only one group can be defined as the `vm.hugetlb_shm_group`. After updating the values of kernel parameters in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, either restart the computer, or run the command `sysctl -p` to make the changes in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file available in the active kernel memory.

Refer: [`hugeadm` command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hugeadm).

> --set-shm-group=
>
> Users in the group specified in /proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group are granted full access to huge pages.
>   The sysctl takes a numeric gid, but this hugeadm option can set it for you, using either a gid or group name.