# IPC SysV Shared memory - shmget(), shmat() does not work

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax 
18446744073692774399
```

Trying to create shmem memory and later overwrite it unsing HUGE Dirty COW vulnerability.

Somehow allocation of MAXMYMEM shows an error "Cannot allocate memory", errorcode 12.

Why it does not work?

allocate.c

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXMYMEM 0x200000 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int shID;
char *myPtr;
int i;

    shID = shmget(2409, MAXMYMEM, IPC_CREAT | SHM_HUGETLB | 0666 );
    if (shID >= 0) {
        myPtr = shmat(shID, 0, 0);
        if (myPtr==(char *)-1) {
            perror("shmat");
        } else {
            for (i=0; i<MAXMYMEM; i++) {
                myPtr[i] = 'A'+i;
            }
            getchar();
            shmdt(myPtr);
        }
    } else {
        perror("shmget");
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**

```
grep -i huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:   1714176 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

**Update 2:**

```
$cat /proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group
0
$uname -a
Linux 4.4.0-101-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 18:29:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try it without the `SHM_HUGETLB` flag and see if that works.

Comment: Yep, it works without SHM_HUGETLB flag

Comment: hmmm .. how can you explain that it works without SHM_HUGETLB? Thanks!

Comment: What's the output from `grep -i huge /proc/meminfo`?

Comment: See Update 1: Thanks!

Comment: what's the output of `cat /proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group` ? and are you running this prog using that group id? also what's your kernel version?

Comment: Added the outputs in Update 2: . How can I specify in my prog group id? Thanks!

Comment: Found also this, this should allocate 256 MB (https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/tools/testing/selftests/vm/hugepage-shm.c) shared huge pages, but it gets the same error: shmget: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: Doesn't the fact that `hugetlb_shm_group == 0` mean no users can map huge pages? This explains why the code works without huge pages, but fails with them.

Comment: Thanks! Well I looked into this. It seems it just specify System GID (group) which is allowed to map Hugepages. See here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849638/how-to-restrict-users-or-applications-from-using-hugepage-support

Comment: BTW I ran my code as root, since normal user isn't privileged to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that on Ubuntu 16.04 the number of Huge Pages was set to 0.

```
$sysctl vm.nr_hugepages
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
```

by changing it to a different value, the program worked!

```
$sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=512
```