# User Application using Hugepage Shared Memory. Allocation error, why?

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory, huge-pages

Trying to execute this sample:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/testing/selftests/vm/hugepage-shm.c

but get:

```
shmget: Cannot allocate memory



shmget(0x2, 268435456, IPC_CREAT|SHM_HUGETLB|0600) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

It is a machine with 8GB RAM and Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel 4.4.0 ia64

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7170        1452        4604          77        1112        5361
Swap:          7623           0        7623


cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[always] madvise never

grep -i huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:    413696 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

cat /proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group
0

cat  /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
18446744073692774399

cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
18446744073692774399
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that `hugetlb_shm_group` is 0 mean no users can map huge pages?

Comment: Thanks! Well I looked into this. It seems it just specify System GID (group) which is allowed to map Hugepages. See here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849638/how-to-restrict-users-or-applications-from-using-hugepage-support

Comment: BTW I ran my code as root, since normal user isn't privileged to do this

Comment: You need to enable hugepage either at boot time or after boot through command line.  As you can see there is no hugepage available based on your meminfo.

Answer (score 1):

From the meminfo, you have no available hugepage can be used, 
You can `sysctl vm.hugepages=20` to enable 40M for this.

For x86_64 arch, 2Mi size is enabled by default, if you want to use 1Gi size, you have to add some parameters as kernel boot arguments.

Refer to:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt